# Rolling calculation of predefined function

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to achieve a rolling calculation by using a predefined function with multiple arguments. The Dataframe to roll on holds the arguments of the function in the columns.

```
def f(x, y):
  return x*y

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((100, 2)), columns=["a", "b"])
df.rolling(5, method="table").apply(lambda z: f(z["a"], z["b"]).sum())
```

> ValueError: Data must be 1-dimensional

How can I best achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't work with a full DataFrame in pure pandas, only by column.

You can however cheat a bit and use the indices:

```
# here we input any column and use it to retrieve the indices
# then we slice internally
def f(s, ref=df):
    return (df.loc[s.index, 'a']*df.loc[s.index, 'b']).sum()

np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((100, 2)), columns=["a", "b"])
df['c'] = df.rolling(5)['a'].apply(f)
```

Example:

```
           a         b         c
0   0.548814  0.715189       NaN
1   0.602763  0.544883       NaN
2   0.423655  0.645894       NaN
3   0.437587  0.891773       NaN
4   0.963663  0.383442  1.754314
..       ...       ...       ...
95  0.398221  0.209844  1.338191
96  0.186193  0.944372  1.376708
97  0.739551  0.490459  1.165852
98  0.227415  0.254356  0.907721
99  0.058029  0.434417  0.705172

[100 rows x 3 columns]
```